# How can I pass a boolean call by reference in ios

Tags: ios

I'd like to pass a boolean NegatiefOfNiet call by reference. How can I do this?

```
- (NSMutableArray *)ontbindInFactoren:(int)product inTabel:(NSMutableArray *)tabel voorAlDanNietNegatief: (BOOL) NegatiefOfNiet
```

I realize that I should have made the procedure like this:

```
  - (bool)ontbindInFactoren:(int)product inTabel:(NSMutableArray *)tabel voorAlDanNietNegatief: (BOOL) NegatiefOfNiet
```

as the tabel has a pointer so I shouldn't have returned the tabel. Problem is that all code is written now, so I'd like to pass the boolean call by reference. How is this done?

Tx

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
BOOL NegatiefOfNiet = NO;
[self ontbindInFactoren:product inTable:tabel voorAlDanNietNegatief:&NegatiefOfNiet];

- (NSMutableArray *)ontbindInFactoren:(int)product inTabel:(NSMutableArray *)tabel voorAlDanNietNegatief:(BOOL *)NegatiefOfNiet
{
    *NegatiefOfNiet = YES;
}
```

Comment: You should always be sure to check that the pointer isn't `nil` or the code will crash. `if (NegatieOfNiet) *NegatieOfNiet = YES;`.

Comment: I'm getting an incompatible integer to pointer conversion within the procedure on the line if (product<0) {NegatiefOfNiet=true;}else{NegatiefOfNiet=false;}.

Comment: @user2984705 You need an asterisk in front of `NegatieOfNiet` since it is a pointer. Just like the code in the answer shows.

Comment: I'm willing to. How can I do so?

Comment: @user2984705 There should be an outlined checkmark next to the answer.  Click this checkmark to mark the answer as the accepted answer.